# DHS TRIP for denied ESTA

Tags: air-travel, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I was recently denied an ESTA. Wasn't given a reason although I did not violate any of the terms. I filled in the DHS TRIP ([Traveller Redress Inquiry Program](https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-trip)) form, citing a denied ESTA as my reason for redress.

What is the normative response time, specifically with using it to appeal a denied ESTA? I submitted the required documents 6 days ago and my application is still under "Pending Paperwork", apparently it takes a long time to sort through. I'm short on time and would like to make my planned trip to the US. Applying for a visa doesn’t seem like an option as wait times are too long.

Comment: I edited it to add a link and to make it less a solicitation of opinions.

Answer (score 6):

DHS TRIP can take [a month](https://onemileatatime.com/department-of-homeland-security-letter/) (or for another anecdote, [17 months](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g28926-i29-k6791911-o20-Last_minute_ESTA_status_change-California.html)) to get a response.

[The recommended procedure](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1074/~/esta-application-denied) if you're denied an ESTA for any reason, even if it's just a frustrating mistake that's not in any way your fault, is to apply for a US visa. If you're in the UK, it's conceivable that the US embassy may be able to grant [an expedited appointment](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/emergency-appointments/) if you need a visa because you were denied an ESTA, so it's worth pursuing that option. A visa is really the best option to resolve this; I would not count on a favorable response from DHS TRIP in time.